# Pattern table in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I want to create a table as given. I have written the code for the first two columns but the output is incorrect. Need help figuring out my mistakes.
Ignore the little imperfections of the image of the table given in the question. They are not part of the output I desire.

**Question-**
[image: Table image]

**My attempt for first two columns-**

```html
<table border="1" width="50%" height="50%">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6"></td>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
    <td rowspan="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="0" colspan="0"></td>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
    <td rowspan="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Output-**
[image: output table]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is what you're after:

```css
table, td {
border: 1px solid #999;
}

table {
width: 100%;
}

td {
height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="4"></td>
  <td rowspan="2"></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How come the third and fourth row display in the 3rd column?